# Can we trade option spreads with more than 4 option legs?

Tags: options, spread-options

I am wondering why most online brokers restrict multi-legged options spread trades to have a maximum of four legs?

Also, is there a broker that allows you to trade say 6 or 8 legged option spreads.

Comment: http://www.cboe.com/cob/cob.aspx may or may not be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is what exchanges recognize as acceptable complex option orders. This is governed by FINRA margin rules like [rule 4210](http://finra.complinet.com/en/display/display.html?rbid=2403&element_id=9383)

Brokers can only execute orders that are recognized by options exchanges. So what brokers can put on a single order ticket is limited. The most complex spreads defined by FINRA rules would be [butterfly spreads](http://optionsforum.net/topic/81/butterfly-options-strategy-in-depth), box spreads and possibly condors.

Clearly you can build as complex options positions as you wish but you would have to leg in/out of those.

Answer (score 0):

Multi-Leg options are just combinations of vanilla options. So you can combine two 4-leg spreads to an 8-leg spread and so on.

I think they offer at most 4 legs because it is the most bought option. I dont see a reasonable trading strategy involving 5 or more legs.

Answer (score -2):

Interactive Brokers accepts orders with more than 4 legs (e.g., 6 or 8) as a single order.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? It's not clear to me what you mean.